# How to choose the Anti-Virus to use?

Tags: networking, virus, administrator, anti-virus, root

There are many Anti-Virus and Internet Security software brands like: Nod32, Kaspersky, Norton, Panda, etc. All of these companies said they are the best, they are the number one. But that no make sense.

How do you know what is the best Anti-Virus of the year?
Is there any statistics that can show which are really better?
What page can we review before choose one of these?
Wich do we use for personal and enterprise environment?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welxoms to Superuser. Unfortunately this is off topic here (mainly opinion based and a product/shopping recommendation)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question is likely to get closed, because it seems to be Opinion-based. There are many factors that you have to consider when selecting a good antivirus programme.
You have to refer multiple sites with reviews, because most of the reviews are based on user experience of their own. That being said, [av-comparatives.org](https://www.av-comparatives.org/consumer/test-results/) seems to be a good start.

A few areas to consider:

1. Pricing Plan  (Free, Freemium or Paid-only)
2. Reviews  (From sites like cnet)
3. Performance  (You have to test them yourself)
4. Compatibility   (Will it work with your OS and its version... etc.)
5. Accuracy (How accurately will it flag antivirus)

Answer (score 1):

There is no absolute authority on antivirus products.

There are a couple of respectable labs, one is [AV-TEST](https://www.av-test.org/en/?r=1), another is [AV-comparitives](https://www.av-comparatives.org) Both make their money from presenting these results, so it's possible that the AV companies themselves must pay for these tests. I don't really know the business model.

All the usual PC magazine-type sites publish their own results too - pcmag, tomshardware, cnet, techradar etc.

Different products drift up & down the tables over time, so you need to take a long view, tempered by the most recent results.

So, you could use these as a guide - certainly never trust any guide that ends up by recommending something you've never heard of, because it's probably their own product [or in some cases an identikit product marketed by many similar scummy companies].